# How to show/hide div based on selected Multiple value in select2 jQuery field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have select2 jquery dropdown which compose of two items
    *For Rent
    *For Sales
If i selected For Rent a certain fields will be displayed under it same as the For sales. The problem is i don't know how i'm gonna display both fields if user selected both in dropdown.

In my code I tried to do it but when user selected just only one it displays both fields

```
$('#for_sales_fields').hide();
$('#for_rents_fields').hide();


$('#property-types-ids').change(function() {

  if($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('#for_sales_fields').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#for_sales_fields').hide();
  }
  if($(this).val() == 2) {
    $('#for_rents_fields').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#for_rents_fields').hide();
  }

  var test = [];
  $.each($('#property-types-ids :selected'), function(){
      test.push($(this).val());
      $('#for_sales_fields').show();
      $('#for_rents_fields').show();
  })

 }
 );
```

### When For Sale is selected

[image]

### When For Rent is selected

[image]

### When both selected it should display both fields

[image]

### FRONT END CODE AUTO GENERATED

[image]

Comment: Have you tried print out `$(this).val()` ?, it should return an array and cannot be compared using `==`

Comment: @Neverever What do you mean by print out ?

Comment: `console.log($(this).val())`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonP It's minimal :)

Comment: @Neverever Ahh, I get the array of the values

Comment: @Miracle but it does not reproduce the issues, there is no HTML provided which provides important context for the selectors you use. Please actually read the link, take note of the parts that say "Complete"

Comment: @JonP My issues already solved see the answer below, that's what i'm talking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:

Initially, you need to keep both div hidden, in change event. Then check the value of the selected value in property type and display your divs

```js
var s2 = $("#property-types-ids").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose property type",
    tags: true
});

var vals = [];

vals.forEach(function(e){
if(!s2.find('option:contains(' + e + ')').length) 
  s2.append($('<option>').text(e));
});

s2.val(vals).trigger("change"); 



$('#for_sales_fields').hide();
$('#for_rents_fields').hide();

$('#property-types-ids').change(function() {

  $('#for_sales_fields').hide();
  $('#for_rents_fields').hide();

  var test = [];
  $.each($('#property-types-ids :selected'), function(){
      test.push($(this).val());
    if($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('#for_sales_fields').show();
    }
    if($(this).val() == 2) {
      $('#for_rents_fields').show();
    }
  })

 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select multiple name="event_type[]" class="form-control" id="property-types-ids">
  <option value="1">For Sale</option>
  <option value="2">For Rent</option>
</select>


<div id ="for_sales_fields">
  #sales fields div
</div>

<div id ="for_rents_fields">
  #Rent fields div
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify it based on my code ? I'm pretty new in doing these

Comment: That's the complete JS code, for the front end it's auto generated will edit my answer

Comment: hi @Miracle if that is you complete js code than you haven't initialize select2 for the $('#property-types-ids') element edit you question will let you know.